# How to find all after effect installed version in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have problem for detecting the all after effects installed version in c# i used this code for getting the name

```
static string[] GetAllInstalledSoftware(string strPrefix)
        {
            const string strUNINSTALL_KEY = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            List<string> listMatches = new List<string>();

            // Enumerate all sub keys found under the "Uninstall" key, each sub key represents a installed software
            foreach (string strSubKey in Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(strUNINSTALL_KEY).GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                // try to get the "DisplayName" for the installed software
                object objValue = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(strUNINSTALL_KEY + @"\" + strSubKey).GetValue("DisplayName");
                if (objValue != null)
                {
                    string strDisplayName = objValue.ToString();

                    // If display name starts with the desired prefix
                    if (strDisplayName.StartsWith(strPrefix))
                    {
                        // -> add it to the result list
                        listMatches.Add(strDisplayName);
                    }
                }
            }
            return listMatches.ToArray();
        }
```

But it only give me only one latest installed name for after effect but i have installed 3 version of after effects CS5, CS6, CC-2014,

so anybody have solution how to find all installed version of after effects?

Comment: Is "after effects" some sort of tool? You may want to consider fixing your keyboard - shift/caps-lock seem to be broken and code/text randomly uses/misses capital letters. Also please explain how this question relates to "asp.net" (which is somehow important for you as post is tagged that way).

Comment: after effects is software of adobe, and i find some solution based on asp.net framework so i tagged with asp.net.

Comment: What are the exact descriptions of After Effects under "Uninstall a program" in the Control Panel? Also, how do you call `GetAllInstalledSoftware` (what's `strPrefix` set to?)